# Extract unique Tags and Count

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

Good morning,

I am trying to run a kusto Query to display unique owner tags to show in a chart the amount of times an owner shows up in azure. I want to have all the distinct owners and cost centers show up but am having trouble figuring out the best way to do that.Below is an example but I need to specify multiple owners to produce a chart that shows all the unique owners in Azure

resources
| where tags['owner'] =~ "Billy"
| summarize count()

Answer (score 1):

This should give you a direction. You'll need to do something similar for the "cost center" property (or update your question to elaborate on which part of your data set it comes from)

```
resources
| extend owner = tostring(tags.owner)
| summarize count() by owner
| render barchart // you can choose a different type of chart
```

given your modified description: *If I have two sets of tags one that is (Owner) and the other is (owner) how would I combine them together in the query?* -> you could do this (assuming you can't fixed the source data, which would be better):

```
union (
    resources
    | extend owner = tostring(tags.owner) // lowercase 'o' in 'tags.owner'
    | summarize count() by owner
), (
    resources
    | extend owner = tostring(tags.Owner) // uppercase 'O' in 'tags.Owner'
    | summarize count() by owner
)
| summarize sum(count_) by owner
```

Comment: If I have two sets of tags one that is (Owner) and the other is (owner) how would I combine them together in the query?

Comment: see updated answer